# Adding permissions for roles on discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hey all found this script for users posting invite links...  Let's say I wanted to whitelist certain channels from not allowing the bot to ban or kick users posting invite links.  Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks.

```js
adminClient.on("message", async message => {
  if (!message.member) return;
  const linkRegex = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(discord\.(gg|io|me|li|com)(\/invite)?)\/.+[a-z0-9A-Z]/
  if (message.content.startsWith("?ban") && message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send("You must mention who you want to ban.")
    mentionedMember.ban().catch(e => message.channel.send(`Something went wrong when banning that user.\n\`${e}\``))
  } else if (message.content.startsWith("?kick") && message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
}
```

Comment: You just want that if the message is sent in a certain channel, not to be banned?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [know the channel ID](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) of the channel that u want to whitelist and add a condition on top of that, this way:

```
if (message.channel.id==WHITELIST_CHANNEL_ID) return;
```